# QtCreator and MinGW GCC 4.8.1

Tags: c++11, mingw, qt-creator

I want to experiment with c++11 code on Windows and actually for what I know the only viable compiler is MinGW gcc 4.8.1-posix-sjlj.

Now the only IDEs I know well are QtCreator and Visual Studio. On VS I cannot use MinGW (or can be complicated).

Qt Creator comes with MinGW GCC 4.7(.?). Now I'm not interested in Qt library. I just want an IDE. Is Qt Creator a good choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt Creator can be installed without any other Qt components. Just download from [here](https://qt-project.org/downloads#qt-creator).

Just use CMake to handle your build and you've got yourself an IDE.

Make sure to point you Qt Creator to your toolchain.

Comment: Is that I don't understand... why cmake? Ok I'll give a try